# Is there any function in d3 for counter?

Tags: d3.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROvCv.png)this is my visualization it displays count values for each bar after transition of 5 min when all bars properly grow in length.
I want to show count values starting from 0 to height of bar. is this possible? if yes kindly help me out.

Comment: This is covered in [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/).

Comment: this is again static data, I am pasting my code here so that you  have better understanding of what I actually want.

Comment: svg.selectAll(".bartext")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.transition()
.delay(290000)
.duration(300000)
.attr("class", "bartext")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("fill", "black")
.style("font-weight","bold")
.attr("x",function (d, i) {
        return  convert.x(d.alarm)+30;
      })
.attr("y", function(d,i) {
    return convert.y(d.value);
})
.text(function(d){
     return d.value;//// here I want to add counter here, from 0 to d.value,
});

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/02/07/using-d3-to-draw-a-bar-chart-with-an-axis-and-some-basic-transitions/                                        this is what, I have done already, but now I am trying to add the value/count[exact status/height of a bar] as bar grows up starting from o to max size of each bar. just like a counter in c++. hope some one understand and answer my question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454993/changing-number-displayed-as-svg-text-gradually-with-d3-transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lars Kotthoff it was very helpful. I am pasting my code here hope it would be helpful for others.
`

```
svg.selectAll(".bartext")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class", "bartext")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("fill", "black")
.style("font-weight","bold")
.attr("x",function (d, i) {
        return  convert.x(d.alarm);
      })
.attr("y", maxHeight)
 .transition()
    .duration(180000)
        .tween("text", function(d) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, d.value),
                prec = (d + "").split("."),
                round = (prec.length > 1) ? Math.pow(10, prec[1].length) : 1;
            return function(t) {
              var j=maxHeight;
                this.textContent = Math.round(i(t) * round) / round;
                svg.selectAll(".bartext")
                .attr("y",function(d){return convert.y(this.textContent)})
              };
        });
```

`